# Steam won't launch Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, games, steam

Just as the title says, I can't get it to open at the moment.

Details: I'm using an Nvidia card, and when Ubuntu was freshly installed on my laptop, I could download and install both Steam and Nvidia drivers and get them to work no problem, I've even played games for 5 days without any inconvenience. But then one day, steam decided to stop loading with the infamous error:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Now here's the case, I've spent like 6-8 hours trying to solve this, going to various forums looking for solutions, here's what I've done so far(at least that I can remember):

1. Deleting Nvidia driver and Steam in various orders through various methods, restarting computer like 20 times in doing that. (fail)
2. Tried to figure out why it couldn't pick up libGL by trying to open that little gear spinning program, that should fail the same way steam does and show why it did, but it didn't fail and showed basically bugger all to me (fail)
3. I've done all the system updating, everything I could imagine, still no results (fail)

Additional IMPORTANT (I guess) info: Now I've got them both installed and I've found that if I select Intel HD graphics card, I can load steam, but if I've Nvidia selected, no luck. Interesting thing to me is, that I can run other linux programs and even games (Like Doom 2 modifier Zandronum) it is just that Steam refuses to work, when Nvidia card is selected.

Last bit: While providing help, keep in mind that I'm a complete novice at Ubuntu so try to keep it as simple as possible, also, I maybe could of done something wrong in the second method or misunderstood something, that's also a possibility, lastly, if I need to provide any other information, just ask nicely, I'll do it as fast as I can.

P.S. Don't hesitate to ask 'Have you tried doing X?' Cause I might have forgotten about it, since I searched for the fix the day before posting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **SOLVED**

So, after approximately another 4 hours of thinking and searching around the net, I deduced that the issue was due to the driver which I selected to install and I was right.

The Nvidia driver that I had was from Software & Updates>>Additional Drivers ,of course, the newest version.

The reason Steam worked 5 days before my post, was that I don't know how but I installed some outdated driver from a .run file, so I basically just recreated the process using the newest Nvidia drivers from their official website, here's what you have to do if you are having the same problem (don't worry, I'm an Ubuntu casual, it will be very easy to follow, also after the first 2 steps you won't be able to see your desktop, so prepare a paper and a pen, and write down these steps before doing anything):

1. Uninstall whatever Nvidia driver you have currently installed, then download drivers that were made EXACTLY for your Nvidia card and linux operating (32-bit or 64-bit) system from the official Nvidia website.
   P.S. if you want the same exact steps as mine, keep the downloaded .run file in Downloads, also, write down its name on your paper, for example, mine was: `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run`
2. Press CTRL+ALT+F2 (the black screen that appears is what's supposed to happen, don't worry)
3. Type in your log-in info (The user name in lowercase letters, for example, mine was: `benas`. Then when asked, type the password)
4. Write `sudo service lightdm stop` or `sudo stop lightdm` whichever seems to be working for you. You'll know that it is working if you get no response from the terminal"
5. Write `sudo init 3`
6. Write `sudo -i` or `sudo su root` You'll know that it's working just by looking at the very left of the line, were you are supposed to type the commands, it should say `root` before your name.
7. Write `cd /home/yourusername(in my case was just: benas)/Downloads` (Or it can be any directory where you put the .run file, just navigate to it)
8. Write `sh The-downloaded-file-name-here.run` (As mentioned earlier, in my case was: `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run`)
9. Press yes and I accept where nescessary, what I also told the installer to do, was to install the 32 bit libraries when it asked me if I wanted, I don't know if that has any impact but you can do it aswell, just to be safe.
10. Type `reboot` when the installer finishes, after this, Steam should load and play games normally.

This all complicating installation method was requiered for me, because I would get the: `you appear to be running an x server` problem, which this method seemed to solve.

P.S. The only downside of the driver from official Nvidia site is that I'm no longer able to select my Intel HD Graphics card, other than that, everything's fine.