# Trying to Install steam with property graphic drivers (Ubuntu 16.04.2)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam

I installed Steam today at all worked fine with Nouveau Drivers but as I installed the Nvidia binary drivers (*version 367.57 and GTX 980*) steam didn't start.

`$steam`

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit  
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically  
Installing breakpad exception handler for   appid(steam)/version(1484790260)  
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found  
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Answer (score 0):

Does mesa libs installed if yes delete them and install 375 in addinional drivers from main server and it should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/a/710966/664497
That fixed it for me.
I've gone on the Nvidia Site and installed another driver in .run format and did this tut